# Trying to train model, but got AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to' with DataLoader PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train model, but getting AttributeError. I'm first time with PyTorch, so I don't know its problem with pre-processing or with DataLoader etc., so need to discover where's problem

Data url [Dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)

Normalization code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
# Create a MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# Normalize each chunk
normalized_chunks = [scaler.fit_transform(chunk.numpy().reshape(-1, 1)) for chunk in chunks]

# Convert the normalized chunks back to PyTorch tensors
normalized_tensors = [torch.tensor(chunk, dtype=torch.float32) for chunk in normalized_chunks]

# Print the normalized tensors
for normalized_tensor in normalized_tensors:
    print(normalized_tensor)
```

Output

```
tensor([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        ...,
        [0.],
        [0.],
        [0.]])
tensor([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        ...,
        [0.],
        [0.],
        [0.]])
tensor([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
```

Standardization code:

```py
mport torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np

# Assuming 'normalized_tensors' is a list of PyTorch tensors where each tensor represents a chunk of normalized data
# iterate through the chunks and standardize them

standardized_tensors = []

for normalized_tensor in normalized_tensors:
    # Convert PyTorch tensor to NumPy array
    chunk = normalized_tensor.cpu().numpy()

    # Calculate mean and standard deviation
    mean = np.mean(chunk)
    std = np.std(chunk)
    
    # Apply standardization (z-score normalization)
    standardized_chunk = (chunk - mean) / std
    
    # Convert the standardized NumPy array back to a PyTorch tensor
    standardized_chunk = torch.tensor(standardized_chunk, dtype=torch.float32)

    # Append the standardized chunk to the list
    standardized_tensors.append(standardized_chunk)
```

Create dataset:

```py
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# Check the size of each tensor in the list
sizes = [tensor.size(0) for tensor in standardized_tensors]

# Identify the index of the tensor with the different size
different_size_index = sizes.index(min(sizes))

# Print the sizes of all tensors for diagnostic purposes
for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
    print(f"Tensor {i} size: {size}")

# Ensure that all tensors have the same size along dimension 0
consistent_size = min(sizes)
for i, tensor in enumerate(standardized_tensors):
    if i != different_size_index:
        # Resize the tensor to have the same size along dimension 0
        standardized_tensors[i] = tensor[:consistent_size]

# Concatenate the standardized tensors along dimension 1
dataset_tensor = torch.cat(standardized_tensors, dim=1)

# Create a TensorDataset without labels
dataset = TensorDataset(dataset_tensor)

# create a DataLoader to batch and shuffle your data if needed
# DataLoader is particularly useful for training neural networks
batch_size = 64  # Set your desired batch size
shuffle = True  # Set to True if you want to shuffle the data during training
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle)
```

Output:

```
....
Tensor 95 size: 1144
```

Problem  loop code:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


model.train()  # Set the model to training mode
running_loss = 0.0

for inputs in train_data_loader:
    inputs = inputs.to(device)  # Move input data to the specified device
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradient buffers
    outputs = model(inputs)  # Forward pass


for inputs in train_data_loader:
    inputs = inputs.to(device)  # Move input data to the specified device
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradient buffers
    outputs = model(inputs)  # Forward pass
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)  # Compute the loss
    loss.backward()  # Backpropagation
    optimizer.step()  # Update weights
        
    running_loss += loss.item()

    # Print the average loss for the current epoch
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}] Loss: {running_loss / len(train_data_loader)}')

print('Finished Training')
```

Error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[158], line 10
      7 running_loss = 0.0
      9 for inputs in train_data_loader:
---> 10     inputs = inputs.to(device)  # Move input data to the specified device
     11     optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradient buffers
     12     outputs = model(inputs)  # Forward pass

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to'
```

Conclusion: I'm not sure is that problem with data or pre-process,
or it requires labels, which I don't know because Data (not pre-process) looks like this:
Thank you

[image]

Comment: What is `train_data_loader`? please can you `print(train_data_loader)`?

Comment: @Goku  '<torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x000001D1D2B38110>' output

Comment: Actually in `for inputs in train_data_loader:` , `inputs` is a `list`. Please go thru these https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html; https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Comment: @CozyCode it doesn't work, it gives `AttributeError: 'DataLoader' object has no attribute 'to'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torch.utils.data.DataLoader` class has a universal architecture in order to be able to return any number of values (usually data and target). So even if you have one value (only data without target) when iterating over dataloader, you will get a list with one value. All you need to do is get this value at index 0.

```
for inputs in train_data_loader:
    inputs = inputs[0].to(device)
```